# Adding array items with one Mysql query not working

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Im trying to add multiple values from array in MySQL with one sql query but Im getting this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/index/test2.php on line 103 Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in /var/www/index/test2.php on line 103
```

Here is code part where its wrong:

```
    $sqlas = array(); 
    foreach( $rezai as $rezas ) 
    { 
          if (!empty($rezas)) {
                    $rezas = str_replace('http://', '', strip_tags($rezas));
          }
          else
          {
                    $rezas = 'empty_rezas';
          }

          $failoID = explode('/', $rezas);

          if (!isset($failoID[2]) || empty($failoID[2])) 
          {
                    $failoID[2] = 'neraID';
          }
          if (isset($rezas) && !empty($rezas)) 
           {
                    $urlr = str_replace('www.mysite.com', '', $rezas);
           }
          $sqlas[] = '("'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $failoID[2]).'", "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $urlr).'", "'.$uzklausaClean.'")';
    }
   $conn->query('INSERT INTO four_failai2 (id, url, uzklausa) VALUES '.implode(','. $sqlas).'');
   $conn->close();
```

The line 103 is this one:

```
$conn->query('INSERT INTO four_failai2 (id, url, uzklausa) VALUES '.implode(','. $sqlas).'');
```

It says Argument must be an array, but I am defining $sqlas as empty array before foreach loop and then I am adding values inside loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Other than that, you are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` isn't as safe as one would hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dot instead of a comma in your implode function.

Change `implode(','. $sqlas)` to `implode(',', $sqlas)`. As it is now, you're trying to concatenate the string containing the comma with an array (e.i. array to string conversion).